# Embed website with iframe in meteor cross domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, iframe, meteor, content-security-policy

A little problem, I could not find a solution for:

- The meteor application works in a local network: Served on `app.local:3000`
- A website (Wordpress, Apache) will be the iframe src

So this is what it looks in meteor:

```
<template name="test">
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        iframe { display: block; background: #000; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
        </style>
    <iframe src="http://mllnm.de/wp-api" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</template>
```

But as I expected:

> Refused to frame 'http://mllnm.de/wp-api' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   http://*.googleapis.com https://*.googleapis.com http://*.gstatic.com
>   https://*.gstatic.com http://*.bootstrapcdn.com
>   https://*.bootstrapcdn.com". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

So what .htaccess-settings/PHP-headers do I have to set to allow embedding mllnm.de on an foreign domain?

*Note: http://mllnm.de/wp-api is just an example page.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Meteor blog post](http://info.meteor.com/blog/defense-in-depth-securing-meteor-apps-with-content-security-policy) describes the [browser-policy](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/browser-policy?__hstc=256467284.2380bbee688e154511ad743b2723a3ed.1432326768112.1445191089038.1445387991462.22&__hssc=256467284.3.1445387991462&__hsfp=271143449) package.

The package can be installed with:

```
$ meteor add browser-policy
```

Using this package you need to set:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowFrameOrigin("http://mllnm.de/wp-api");
```

to allow http://mllnm.de/wp-api to be framed.

There is no PHP in Meteor. `.htaccess` creates access rules that govern how your site can be accessed, not what other sites it can iframe.

Comment: Oh, I just thought I had to set something on the iframe-server-side - thank you very much for this help!